# Keep Space above a fixed background you scroll up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a background that when you scroll down through JS I attach a fixed class to it which causes it to become a fixed attachment, but the background image won't start disappearing behind the content until it reaches the top and I would like there to be a little space say 20 - 40px of space above the background image while the content scrolls over it.

You can see this in my example at http://jsfiddle.net/4VkBL/

When the page starts there is space above the background but once it gets to the point of where it is being scrolled the background touches the top which i would still like there to be that space between the BG and top of the page.

```
#about-banner {
background-image: url('http://hearthable.com/img/hearthable/about/test.jpg');
width: 700px;
height: 325px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
-moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
border-top-left-radius: 5px;
border-top-right-radius: 5px;
}

.about-fixed {
    background-attachment: fixed;
 }

 $(document).ready(function () {
 var top = $('#about-banner').offset().top - 20 - parseFloat($('#about-  banner').css('marginTop').replace(/auto/, 0));
 $(window).scroll(function (event) {
     // what the y position of the scroll is
     var y = $(this).scrollTop();

     // whether that's below the form
     if (y >= top) {
         // if so, ad the fixed class
         $('#about-banner').addClass('about-fixed');
     } else {
         // otherwise remove it
         $('#about-banner').removeClass('about-fixed');
     }
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `background-position` equal to the margin you need, and you should be good to go:

```css
#about-banner {
    background-position:0 40px;
    /* ... */
}
```

Also, for this to work ok, you don't actually need any js. Simply add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the banner; in this case, you don't actually need your `top` id'd div either. I updated your fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/4VkBL/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/4VkBL/1/)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly in the fiddle but when I try it on my actual site the background doesn't fill up the actual div you can see here http://hearthable.com/test/

Comment: How come the border radius changes when scrolling up?

Comment: What do you mean? The border radius should stay the same. I don't see it change.

Comment: I mean that when I look at the fiddle, the top left corner is rounded at first and when I start to scroll, it becomes squared.

Comment: @KaivoAnastetiks I believe it's because it's only the background that's fixed, the div `#about-banner` will still move on scroll and thus the border radius too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS background-position for the 'about-fixed' class.

```
.about-fixed {
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: 8px 40px;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f95Qy/1/

Comment: Thanks, although if you take a look at it on my site when I do that and it scrolls down to the height where it adds fixed class the background image gets resized for some reason, do you know how to prevent that? http://hearthable.com/test/

Comment: It appears on my site i need to add background-position: 355px 40px; Where is that 355px coming from?